# How can I use only static or shared libraries?

Tags: c++, libraries

I've recently read about the difference between static and shared libraries, but application, that I've made with visual studio and GLUT require both of them. Linker says that there's undefined reference when I try to use only dynamic. Windows says that I need "glut32.dll" for app to work. Maybe I understood something wrong?

Comment: Not sure what do you mean. But whether library is linked statically or dynamically depends or rather is more connected onto how you access it within your program. You can still link a `.dll` statically.

Comment: As I understood, I can use only static libs to reach the single executable with all libs in it, or use only dynamic libs to reach light executable with lots of dll's

Comment: Static linking is necessary for libraries that aren't available as DLL's, and if there is no .LIB version of a library, you need to use it as a DLL. You can't make one into the other (trivially). You will also need a "stub library" for a DLL (this is basically the "hook" or "connection" between the application and the DLL).

Comment: So, I need to use both of these?

Comment: Maybe you can say the library you are trying to link statically. Some libraries are typically distributed as DLL only, so you have to recompile them if you want to link statically

Comment: Without understanding exactly which libraries you are using [and being familiar with those libraries], it's pretty difficult to answer exactly what you need or don't need. We build some of our test-executables as completely statically linked files where I work. It's a pain, as final file is around 100MB, and with 3-4 such files that need to be copied from the build machine to a network location, and then run, it would be much easier to just copy one version of the large commmon parts, and then have a small(ish) executable. But it means we can take the binary and run that on a another system.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The lib you are referring to doesn't contain any actual code but it is just used to load the dll by providing additional information.

The h file also just provides information on the signatures used by the dll's functions

Take a look at: https://stackoverflow.com/a/11552463/1938163